# Maximum MST in graph with specified weights

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

In complete graph $K_{n}$ exactly $n$ edges has weight $1$, the remaining edges have weight $2$. What is the maximum weight of MST in this graph? For which weight distributions is the maximum achieved?

Ok I think that only edges with weight $1$ will be in MST? So the answer is $n * 1$ ?

Comment: How many edges are there in the MST?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi 5?

Comment: Five for what value of $n$?

Comment: @FabioSomenzi $n-1$?

Comment: Yes, $n-1$.  Next, you have $n(n-1)/2$ edges in $K_n$, $n$ of which have weight $1$.  How many edges have weight $2$?  Are there enough of those edges to form an MST of weight $2(n-1)$?  (Remember, you are interested in a spanning tree of *maximum* weight.)  You may want to try out a few small values of $n$.  This is not the final step in solving the problem, but it's a good intermediate step.

Comment: We have $n(n-3)/2$ edges with weight $2$. In worst case, MST has weight $n(n-3)$ combined, so this is the maximum possible weight of MST in this case?

Comment: $n(n-3)$ would be the weight if you could use all the weight-$2$ edges.  However, a spanning tree of a connected graph with $n$ vertices has $n-1$ edges, as you noted earlier.  If $n$ is large, $n(n-3)/2$ is greater than $n-1$, while for small $n$, it is not enough.